# Is it possible in Delphi XE4 to change the app short title without making it the same as the Project dpr name?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey-fm2, delphi-xe4, delphi-ios

I am writing my first delphi-powered iPhone app.  I have created it but I would like it to be named something other than the name of the .dpr file because dpr files cannot contain spaces, for instance, EXE names are not always the same as the human-readable name one might assign an App.

Wherease in Windows Delphi apps the EXEs are named the same as the .dpr file which is fine because the english name in your shortcut, or your localized name on your desktop or in your start menu in any other non-english location are not necessarily the same as your project name. In iOS an app short name might include a space, whereas a Delphi project name can not, so I am quite surprised to see that the two are hard-linked together.

In XCode, you can set your bundle name, your project name, and your visible name on the iOS home screen all separately.

My question is, since I have just installed Delphi XE4 (RTM) today, and I'm trying it out:

1. Can I set the bundle ID somewhere inside the project options? I can't seem to find it. Bundle id's are very important for any app that is heading towards the app store and yet I can't see a UI element where you can set it.
2. Can I also set up a display name somewhere?
3. Can I see and edit the app's .plist (the property list that Apple requires all apps to have on iOS) somewhere or is it generated for me with no chance to see or modify it?  It seems the .plist file is on disk in my Debug\ folder in windows, which means Delphi XE4 sees it as an output artifact and not as an input source document, as it would have been in an Xcode project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, under Project Options you will find Version Information. For iOS apps, this is the bundle information. You can leave most alone but there is a CFBundleDisplayName property for changing the display name. You can set your other bundle info here too.

[Xe4 Docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Version_Info)