# Delphi-XE4: Rename bundle/directory name for Application

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I am currently trying to create the Mac App store version of my Firemonkey application. My problem is, that the created bundle and pkg file names are not those I want:

[image]

Instead of daform.app, I want something like "DA-FormMaker.app".

My question is, is there a setting where I can configure that in Delphi (I am using XE4)? 
Currently its just using the Delphi project name and its get installed in applications with that name.

I tried to rename the bundle manually and created the pkg file via command line, but it still installs with the old name:

```
macbook:da-Air da$ sudo installer -store -pkg DA-FormMaker.pkg -target /
installer: Note: running installer as an admin user (instead of root) gives better Mac App Store fidelity
installer: DA-FormMaker.pkg has valid signature for submission: 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: ...
installer: Installation Check: Passed
installer: Volume Check: Passed
installer: Bundle de.dasoftware.daformmaker will be relocated to /Applications/daform.app
installer: Starting install
```

Is there a way how this can be done? Maybe I am just blind and cannot find the setting in the IDE.

Thanks in advance.

AndyI

Comment: I don't develop for OSX/iOS, but with XE5 Android this is done on the Project/Options dialog, in the Version Info portion. You might see if [this info](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Version_Info#Mac_OS_X_and_iOS_Version_Info) helps, particulary the section on Key/Value Listbox and CFBundleName/CFBundleDisplayName

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately this does not change the output name of the bundle for OSX applications.

Comment: OK. That's why I posted a comment and not an answer. Like I said, I don't do Mac/Apple.

Comment: You might want to see [this previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16182047/62576), which says the CFBundleDisplayName is the correct solution. :-) Also, see [the XE4 docwiki here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Preparing_an_iOS_Application_for_Deployment). You have to deploy the modified plist after changing the version info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to the comments above from Ken White, which gave me a good hint I managed to come up with a solution.

I was not able to change that in Delphi-XE4 itself. I changed the bundle name as suggested above, but the output was still the same (daform.pkg).

So I renamed the daform.app to DA-FormMaker.app and build the pkg file on my own:

```
productbuild --component DA-FormMaker.app /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" DA-FormMaker.pkg
```

The test installation with the command

```
installer -store -pkg DA-FormMaker.pkg -target /
```

installed the application correctly into the /Applications/DA-FormMaker.app folder.